# Problem with psr/container

Tags: 10, upgrading

I like to update drupal from 9 to 10.

I used the update status to get a clean environment with 100% compatibility.
I uninstalled drush.

Then I run the following commands:

```
composer remove drupal/console --no-update
composer remove drupal/upgrade_status --no-update
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10.1.1' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10.1.1' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10.1.1' --no-update
composer remove drupal/core --no-update
composer require 'drupal/core-dev:^10.1.1' --dev --no-update
```

When trying to update with `composer update -W --dry-run` I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.1.1, ..., 10.2.3] require psr/container ~2.0.2 -> found psr/container[2.0.2] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.0).
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.1, ..., 10.2.3].
```

The `composer why-not drupal/core ^10.1.1` gives me the following errors:

```
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///home/.local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:879
Deprecation Notice: Using ${var} in strings is deprecated, use {$var} instead in phar:///home/.local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php:884
drupal/devel                    4.2.1   requires          drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/console (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/console (but v4.4.49 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/dependency-injection (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/dependency-injection (but v4.4.49 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/event-dispatcher (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/event-dispatcher (but v4.4.44 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/filesystem (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/filesystem (but v4.4.42 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/finder (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/finder (but v4.4.44 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/http-foundation (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/http-foundation (but v4.4.49 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/http-kernel (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/http-kernel (but v4.4.51 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/mime (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/mime (but v5.4.13 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/routing (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/routing (but v4.4.44 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/serializer (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/serializer (but v4.4.47 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/validator (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/validator (but v4.4.48 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/process (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/process (but v4.4.44 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          symfony/yaml (^6.4)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  symfony/yaml (but v4.4.45 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          twig/twig (^3.5.0)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  twig/twig (but v2.16.0 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          guzzlehttp/guzzle (^7.5)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  guzzlehttp/guzzle (but 6.5.8 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          guzzlehttp/psr7 (^2.4.5)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  guzzlehttp/psr7 (but 1.9.1 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          asm89/stack-cors (^2.1)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  asm89/stack-cors (but 1.3.0 is installed)
drupal/core                     10.2.3  requires          psr/log (^3.0)
drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       does not require  psr/log (but 1.1.4 is installed)
```

I looked at all possible migration instructions but they did not work.
How to get out of the psr dependency hell.

Thank you very much.

**Edit 2024-02-21:**
I also removed `drupal/devel` but the error still occurs.

Here is the content of the composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "google/charts",
                "version": "45",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "extra": {
                    "installer-name": "google_charts"
                },
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                "require": {
                    "composer/installers": "~1.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "aferrandini/phpqrcode": "^1.0",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "*",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/background_image": "^2.0",
        "drupal/bootstrap_library": "^2.0",
        "drupal/charts": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/config_update": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.1.1",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.1.1",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.1.1",
        "drupal/ctools": "^4.0",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.15",
        "drupal/entity_print": "^2.6",
        "drupal/fontawesome": "^2.13",
        "drupal/fullcalendar_view": "^5.1",
        "drupal/jwt": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/libraries": "^4.0",
        "drupal/login_destination": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/login_history": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/menu_link_config": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/nodeaccess": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
        "drupal/redis": "^1.7",
        "drupal/rest_api_authentication": "^1.1",
        "drupal/restui": "^1.20",
        "drupal/simple_oauth": "^5.2",
        "drupal/slick_extras": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^2.6",
        "drupal/token": "^1.5",
        "drupal/vefl": "^3.0",
        "drupal/verf": "^2.0",
        "drupal/view_custom_table": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_add_button": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^4.0",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.2@beta",
        "drupal/webform_content_creator": "^4.0",
        "google/charts": "45",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "~2.1",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.11",
        "psr/container": "^1.0",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "~6",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "vendor-dir": "vendor",
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "endroid/installer": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "sniffer:php8": "phpcs -p ./web/modules/contrib/esg --standard=vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility/PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 8.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
            },
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "./web"
            },
            "file-mapping": {
                "[web-root]/.htaccess": false
            }
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^10.1.1",
        "kint-php/kint": "^5.0",
        "mglaman/drupal-check": "^1.2",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.4",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.7"
    }
}
```

Comment: RIght at the top, it shows the version of Devel conflicts: `drupal/devel                    4.2.1   requires          drupal/core (^8.8 || ^9)`. Remove devel. Add it back after upgrading.

Comment: Also, is psr/container mentioned literally in composer.json? Reading the errors suggests that is perhaps also the case.

Comment: @cilefen – I've also already seen this as a result of merged composer.jsons from merge plugin.

Comment: @schulle877 – Add your composer.json

Comment: @leymannx True, that would look the same.

Comment: Thank you so far.
I removed drupal/devel bute the error still occurs. Please see the composer.json above.

Comment: Then I removed the psr/container-line from the composer.json completely. Afterwards the update works. I still get an error on updating, but this seems to be, because I still use the deprecated module kint. I will retry with removing kint before the upgrade an will report as soon as possible.